# How do I link user's data to the user in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have created a basic library app that allows users to store a collection of books. I have implemented the firebase sign in system but now I am not sure how to link user to their collection. My plan is:

- Make a collection called `library`
- Add `book`s to the `library` whenever **anyone** adds a book
- For the above book object add a user id field
- To retrieve the read books of the current user for display, just filter the data with the user_id

Is this an appropriate method? If not, how should I go about it?

I am unsure because storing a user_id field and browsing through all books to find the current user's books doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Why is Javascipt tagged in an android question?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a user_id to the book object, then whenever you are searching for anything for a single user, you will need to go through the entire list of books and the entire list of users.

If, however, you create a table for 'Books_By_User_Id' and underneath that you create a branch for each user and then underneath that insert the id of the book they choose, then you will cut down dramatically on the amount of searching.

If you then want to search you ca go straight to 'Books_By_User_Id/userid/' and return just those books belonging to that user.

Comment: table in firebase?

Comment: I mean the Realtime Database. I assumed you were using Realtime Database (possibly a silly assumption). Where are you storing your data?

Comment: You can create a collection called users and add document for each user that has an array of users books.

Comment: @WarrenHarding firestore

Comment: I normally use Firebase Realtime Database rather than Firestore, but Firestore is a very similar alternative.